# datagridview not showing the first row vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

hi so i have this list that im currently using on a combobox that's why i have the `idcategoria = 0` with the `nomeCategoria = "Select your Category"`so the combobox default item would be "select your category". 
here is the code of the list

```
Public Shared Function ObterTodosC() As List(Of Ccategoria)
    Dim lstTodos As List(Of Ccategoria) = New List(Of Ccategoria)

    Dim p As Ccategoria = New Ccategoria()
    p.IdCategoria = 0
    p.NomeCategoria = "select your category"
    lstTodos.Add(p)

    Try
        Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()

            con.ConnectionString = myDAC._connectionString
            Using cmd As SqlCommand = con.CreateCommand()

                cmd.CommandText = "select * from Categoria"
                con.Open()
                Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While dr.Read()
                    Dim p As Ccategoria = New Ccategoria()
                    p.IdCategoria = dr.GetInt32(0)
                    p.NomeCategoria = dr.GetString(1)
                    lstTodos.Add(p)
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As SqlException
        Throw ex
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
    Return lstTodos
End Function
```

Now i want to use the same list on a datagridview and i wanted to know if there is a way to not show the id = 0 on the datagridview or do i have to create another list without the idCategorie = 0 for the datagridview, any ideas on this? thanks

Comment: Create another list from already loaded: `Dim newList = lstTodos.Skip(1).ToList()`.

Comment: Not related to the question - but you can remove `try ... catch`. You not handling thrown exceptions - so you can make your code little bid more clearer

Comment: @Fabio im am handling the thrown exeptions when i link the list to the combobox and or datagridview

Comment: i just didnt post here the code of the combobox because it wasnt necessary

Comment: oh and @Fabio i didnt know of the existence of the .skip thanks will try it tytyty ,(ps:could you make an actual answer to the question so i can validate?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another list from already loaded

```
Dim newList = lstTodos.Skip(1).ToList()
```

`Skip` method will return new collection without first item.
Notice that this approach will work only when `- Select your Category -` item is a first item in the list.

Or change your method to return list without `- Select your Category -` item and add it only when you need.

```
Public Shared Iterator Function ObterTodosC() As IEnumerable(Of Ccategoria)
    Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()

        con.ConnectionString = myDAC._connectionString
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = con.CreateCommand()

            cmd.CommandText = "select * from Categoria"
            con.Open()
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            While reader.Read()
                Yield New Ccategoria With
                {
                    .IdCategoria = reader.GetInt32(0),
                    .NomeCategoria = reader.GetString(1)
                } 
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Then you can create list of categories for datagridview

```
Dim forDataGridView = ObterTodosC().ToList()

Dim notSelectedCategory As New Ccategoria With
{
    .IdCategoria = 0,
    .NomeCategoria = "select your category"
}  
Dim forComboBox = forDataGridView.ToList()
forComboBox.Insert(0, notSelectedCategory)
```

With this approach your remove side effect from `ObterTodosC` method.
So method responsibility will be only load items from database

Comment: No, where you see I am mixing?

Comment: Dim notSelectedCategory As New Ccategoria With
{
    .IdCategoria = 0
    .NomeCategoria = "select your category"
}

Comment: isnt that c# code ? because int vb it doesnt need { right?

Comment: and this Dim forDataGridView = ObterTodosC().ToList()

Comment: This is valid `vb.net` code check [Object Initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385125.aspx)

Comment: `ToList()` will create new instance of `List`. You need call `ObterTodosC().ToList()` because I changed `ObterTodosC()` to return `IEnumerable` - you can ommit it, and change to return `List`